# simple LINQ to XML query won't work

Tags: c#, xml, performance, linq

This Works , but very slow,

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetNames(string prefixText, int count)
 {
    XmlDocument xmlArtist = new XmlDocument();
    xmlArtist.Load(string.Format(" http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettopartists&api_key={0}&limit=100", key));
    List<string> topartists = new List<string>();
    foreach (XmlNode node in xmlArtist.SelectNodes("lfm/artists/artist"))
    {
        string a = node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText.ToString();
        if (a.Contains(prefixText))
        {
            topartists.Add(a);
        }

    }

    return topartists;
```

I want to turn that into a LINQ query to speed things up, I have not used LINQ in a while and been looking at a lot of examples and cannot figure out why this won't work.

```
        [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetNames(string prefixText, int count)
 {
     List<string> topartists = new List<string>();
     XElement element = XElement.Load("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettopartists&api_key=...&limit=100");
     IEnumerable<XElement> artists =
     from el in element.Elements("artist")
     where el.Element("name").Value.Contains(prefixText)
     select el;
     foreach (XElement el in artists)
         topartists.Add(el.Value);
     return topartists;
```

THis is part of XML I have working with:

```
 <lfm status="ok">
   <artists page="1" perPage="100" totalPages="10" total="1000">
    <artist>
     <name>Coldplay</name> 
     <playcount>849564</playcount> 
     <listeners>124389</listeners> 
     <mbid>cc197bad-dc9c-440d-a5b5-d52ba2e14234</mbid> 
     <url>http://www.last.fm/music/Coldplay</url> 
     <streamable>1</streamable> 
     <image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/214667.png</image> 
     <image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/214667.png</image> 
     <image size="large">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/214667.png</image> 
     <image size="extralarge">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/214667.png</image> 
     <image size="mega">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/_/214667/Coldplay.png</image> 
   </artist>
      <artist>
        <name>Radiohead</name> 
        <playcount>960812</playcount> 
        <listeners>104849</listeners> 
        <mbid>a74b1b7f-71a5-4011-9441-d0b5e4122711</mbid> 
        <url>http://www.last.fm/music/Radiohead</url> 
        <streamable>1</streamable> 
        <image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/24688757.png</image> 
        <image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/24688757.png</image> 
        <image size="large">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/24688757.png</image> 
        <image size="extralarge">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/24688757.png</image> 
        <image size="mega">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/_/24688757/Radiohead.png</image> 
      </artist>
      <artist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Elements()` only returns you the direct children, but your root element is `lfm`, so your only child element is `artists` which doesn't match "artist" - so there are no matching elements. You can fix your query like this:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> artists =
     from el in element.Element("artists").Elements("artist")
     where el.Element("name").Value.Contains(prefixText)
     select el;
```

I doubt that this Linq to XML query will be much faster than your previous query though since it is essentially doing the same work.

Comment: I see, thanks,  I did try element.Element("artists/artist")  but it didn't like that ,

Comment: An alternative would be using `from el in element.Descendants("artist")` but that will be slightly less performant

Comment: Is there anyway I can store this data temporarly , and not have to request this XML everytime?  the LINQ was just as slow.  I cannot access Session State, Cookies, or variables from static methods from this method used to populate AutoCompleteExtender?

Comment: @ScottSelby: You can save the results in a static variable